# CodeIgniter - Undefined variable & Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: codeigniter, variables, controller, undefined

I'm trying to get data from API in my Controller and pass the data to the View. But it don't seem working and causing error:

**Message:Undefined variable: data** and
**Message:Trying to get property of non-object**

Both errors happen in my View.php, on the line when I call variable $data.

This is part of my controller related to data I want to get

```
$jdwl['jadwal'] = $this->bolalob->api('schedules/bydate|'.$start.'/'.$end.'/10');
$data['jadwal'] = $this->load->view('jadwal', $jdwl, TRUE);

$template['content'] = $this->load->view('jadwal',$data, TRUE);
$this->load->view('template', $template);
```

And this is my view

```
<div class="float-left first-column">
    <div class="box box-shadow red round-top round-bottom">
      <div class="title-box"><strong>JADWAL</strong> TV</div>
      <ul class="text-center no-padding">
        <?php if ($data->data == 'no data') { ?>
        <li class="jadwal-tv"><strong>Belum ada jadwal</strong>
        </li>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <?php foreach ($data->data as $key=>$row) { ?>
        <?php if ($key == 0) { ?>
        <li class="jadwal-tv"><strong><?php echo $row->team_1->name; ?></strong><br />VS<br /><strong><?php echo $row->team_2->name; ?></strong><br /><span><?php echo $row->television; ?> <?php echo date('d/m/y H:i', $row->pubdate); ?> WIB</span></li>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <li class="side-padding">
          <strong><?php echo $row->team_1->name; ?></strong> vs <strong><?php echo $row->team_2->name; ?></strong>
          <br />
          <?php echo $row->television; ?> <?php echo date('d/m/y H:i', $row->pubdate); ?> WIB
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($key == 5) break; ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>    
  </div>
```

The error happens to $data on line the 5 and 9. I've googled it and tried to use $data['jadwal'] instead of $data in my view but I didn't seem working too.

Anyone can help me with this?
Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

In your view no need to acess the `$data` array.
you can directly call your data key as a variable.

Ex:

**In controller**

```
$data['myVar']="Some string";
$this->load->view('viewName',$data);
```

**In view**

```
echo $myVar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following view page..

```
<div class="float-left first-column">
<div class="box box-shadow red round-top round-bottom">
    <div class="title-box"><strong>JADWAL</strong> TV</div>
    <ul class="text-center no-padding">
        <?php if (empty($jadwal)) { ?>
            <li class="jadwal-tv"><strong>Belum ada jadwal</strong>
            </li>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <?php foreach ($jadwal as $key => $row) { ?>
                <?php if ($key == 0) { ?>
                    <li class="jadwal-tv"><strong><?php echo $row->team_1->name; ?></strong><br />VS<br /><strong><?php echo $row->team_2->name; ?></strong><br /><span><?php echo $row->television; ?> <?php echo date('d/m/y H:i', $row->pubdate); ?> WIB</span></li>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <li class="side-padding">
                        <strong><?php echo $row->team_1->name; ?></strong> vs <strong><?php echo $row->team_2->name; ?></strong>
                        <br />
                        <?php echo $row->television; ?> <?php echo date('d/m/y H:i', $row->pubdate); ?> WIB
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ($key == 5) break; ?>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm trying this but now I get "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" on line `<?php foreach ($jadwal as $key => $row) { ?>`. Any idea why? Thaanks a lot! :-)